# How to run gradle from the command line for Android Studio when versions mismatch?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got an Android Studio project and have been building it just using Build/Rebuild Project - and it builds fine.

However I'm making additions to the build.gradle file and am having an issue using AS as often the output in the Gradle Console within AS just vanishes. This means if I've made a mistake with the build.gradle additions I can't see what the problem is.

So I thought I'd run things from the command line. So I just type 'gradle' from my mac's terminal window but I get this:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/Cequint/Desktop/CityIDGradle/android/CityID/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to grade-2.2-all.zip
```

The gradle-wrapper.properties file in AS contains this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Yet if I type 'gradle -version' from the command line it shows I have Gradle 2.10 installed.

I tried changing the cradle-wrapper.properties file in AS to contain grade-2.2-all.zip as it said in the error message, but it made no difference.
I also tried changing it to be grade-2.10-all.zip but its still the same error message.

So the question is:
1) what can I update in the AS gradle files to build from the command line?

2) If I have a different version of gradle downloaded onto the mac, than got installed with AS. How can I download the version with AS to be the same i.e. to be v2.10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `gradle` from the command line, it invokes gradle from your system path, which apparently is gradle 2.10

When you add a wrapper section to your gradle.build file, as is the case with Android Studio projects, you will see a gradlew.bat and a gradlew shell script in the project root folder. These scripts will invoke (and download if required) the version of gradle defined in your wrapper section.

TL;DR: Run `./gradlew` instead of `gradle`